# This Potentiometer Keeps Catching Fire And I Can't Locate The Short

Tags: capacitor, resistors, short-circuit, triac, diac

Device: KADA 852 Hotair rework station (not 852D)

VR9 keeps catching on fire and R42 is half toasted but still keeping its resistance, I removed and checked CA12 and CA13 and they are not shorted. Tested T11 & diodes D17 to D24 in place and they seemed okay. I'm not sure what else could be shorting out causing so much current to run into these resistors.

VR9 has a dial and sets the pump speed/power, R42 sets the minimum pump speed, VR11 and R47 trim VR9 and R42.

Test condition: to narrow down the cause, this issue is present when I connector labeled "RED" has BRN connected briefly to BLU so C9 charges and then returned to connect "BRN" to "WHT". This way the left part of the circuit is not powered, just the relay connecting AC to the right side and AC running to D17. The circuit runs until the delay set by C9 runs out and the relay disconnects.

In this schematic, the missing part on the left is unconnected, 220 VAC enters on the right "BLU labeled connector", a switch at connector labeled "RED" on the left connects either BRN to WHT or BRN to BLU, at connector labeled "BLU" there is a diaphragm pump connected.

PS: R44 & R45 = 30K each instead of 300.
[image: Hot Air Station Pump Drive Circuit]

Comment: Cut the blue wire! But seriously, what is this circuit supposed to do and what is it connected to? Where did you get it?

Comment: EDIT: In switch in BLU position is on and normal operation of the pump, switch in WHT position is a delayed off.

Comment: I think that if you want help with this you need to mark up the schematic with words or symbols like 'LIVE', 'NEUTRAL', 'LOAD' instead of BLU RED BRN, etc. Is there a load connected when the fault happens? "*... at connector labeled "BLU" there is a diaphragm pump connected*" at only one terminal? Is the other pump wire connected somewhere? Hit the [edit] link and add information to the question rather than in bits and pieces in the comments.

Comment: @BrianDrummond It's one of three circuits in my hotair rework station that I had to reverse engineer. KADA 852, not 852D. It drives the air pump, on and delayed off with a variable speed controlled with VR9.

Comment: That's a start, but please add all new info and correction to the question, not the comments. So it's a hot air rework station. Is it a reputable brand (Weller/Metcal etc) or some no-name brand? Link to its datasheet or website. One practical point : the schematic has VR9/R42 and VR11/R47 in parallel doing the same job. That can't be right, for a start. What do their labels say?

Comment: It's a chinese brand, KADA, model 852. VR9 is the dial that the users sets the pump speed/power with, R42 probably sets the minimum speed, VR11 & R47 are for trimming.

Comment: [Edit] the information **into the question**. Don't bury relevant information in the comments!

Comment: If R42 is half-toasted, the colour bands may have changed colour, so if that's how you found it's value, it could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, too much current is flowing through the series R42/VR9 devices. A quick and dirty fix: if the VR9 pump control setting does not need to be at minimum rotation (0 Ω), and **if the rework station functions normally** other than the burnt pot, **make R42 larger**, perhaps 10kΩ. The issue might have been poor design, where too much current is passed when the pot is set to minimum.

Comment: When I set the speed higher meaning that the pot resistance is lower, it burns. The original design worked for years, changing it for a larger value is not a solution. Something else is broken and I'm not sure what.